# Selenium WebDriver Java Maven input date with sendkeys isn't working

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to input a date into a date field that has a calendar plugin like every reservation site has. Here's my code:

```
WebElement checkIn = driver.findElement(By.id("check-in"));
checkIn.sendKeys("08/31/15");       
WebElement checkOut = driver.findElement(By.id("check-out"));
checkOut.sendKeys("09/06/15");
```

This isn't inputting the date when I run the script. The date format is correct. What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you manually input this value (by typing it, with no mouse)?

Comment: I don't suppose you can share the link to the page? Can you put text in other controls on the page? Are these controls in an `IFRAME` or something?

Comment: For example: [hotels.com](http://hotels.com).

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might want to try is to run a JavaScript snippet through your `WebDriver` instance to change the input's value. Something like this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$('#check-in').prop('value', '08/31/15');");
```

Comment: but this doesn't actually test that it works.  from a user standpoint, I wont be typing that into console to force the property.  I will be interacting with the page.

Comment: That's true. You won't be testing that the input is working, but you'll still be able to test the system's behavior given that input.

Comment: definitely a solution, which is why i'm not downvoting, but for the OP's edification, this bypasses what the user actually does.

Comment: I'm pretty new to automation scripting so I'm not familiar with your solution. I tried pasting your code above mine and the error is: JavascriptExecutor cannot be resolved to a type. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you imported it? `import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;`

Answer (score 0):

So I've figured out how to resolve my specific issue by throwing in some Thread.sleep(3000)'s all over the place. The calendar plugin that I'm testing automatically fills the check out date after you input a check in date. So when my script was sending a check out date, it was just adding it onto the end of the auto date. Obviously the plugin didn't understand this and just set the dates to the current date and the following day. The solution is to clear the check out date before writing in the desired date.

My code now:

```
WebElement checkIn = driver.findElement(By.id("qf-0q-localised-check-in"));
checkIn.sendKeys("08/30/15");
WebElement checkOut = driver.findElement(By.id("qf-0q-localised-check-out"));
checkOut.clear();
checkOut.sendKeys("09/06/15");
```